# Default site language based on the ip with rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, geocoding

I've a multilanguage site, based on the localization of the visitor (his ip), I'll use one language or another (setting the I18n.locale).

i.e: for a visitor from France, the default language will be french, for a visitor from US the default language will be english.

Which gem do you recommend for that, there is [a wide range of choice](http://ruby-toolbox.com/categories/geocoding___maps.html).

Thanks

Comment: make sure users can override this. I hate imdb - it translates movie titles to Russian because I'm located in Russia and I can't find a way to override this.

Answer (score 1):

Some countries have more than one official language, or multiple commonly spoken languages. For these countries, you may want to consider defaulting to the most prevalent spoken and then display a ranked list by prevalance. You can get the official and common languages spoken and percentage from the CIA World Factbook listing on country languages:

https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/fields/2098.html

If you need to map the language to the ISO 639-1 alpha-2 or alpha-3 codes, you can get that information from the US Library of Congress at:

http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/English_list.php

The OpenGeoCode.Org Team
Andrew